# Laravel cookies comes with encryption, why?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I got the following serivce provider:

```
class CartServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {

    }

    public function register() {
        $this->app->singleton(\Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart::class, function($app) {
            return new \Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart($app['request']);
        });
    }
}
```

And my Cart class, where I got this:

```
$this->id = (request()->cookie('cart_id')) ? request()->cookie('cart_id') : false;
```

But `request()->cookie('cart_id')` returns encrypted string. If I will do it in any controller, it works fine. Why? What should I do to use it in Cart class?Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequences of Laravel bootstrapping a request is this (v5.6): (CMIIW)

1. `index.php` is called
2. `\Illuminate\Foundation\Application` created
3. `HttpKernel` registered. This register your middlewares
4. `Console Kernel` registered. This defines console commands
5. `Exception Handler` registered. This defines exception handlers
6. `HttpKernel` instantiated. This instantiate all middlewares, plus **boot/register all your service providers**
7. Create global `request` instance. Pass it to `HttpKernel` to handle incoming request.
8. Middleware `EncryptCookies` called, **cookies decrypted**
9. Sending `request` to other middlewares to process
10. Send `request` to router, router dispatch to controller
11. ...
12. Before sending response to browser, **cookies encrypted back** in `EncryptCookies`

---

Cookie is remained encrypted in Step 1 - Step 7. Your `CartServiceProvider` is trying to obtain a cookie that is yet to be decrypted at Step 6, which is not possible. Consider either

1. Decrypt the cookie by yourself (using just `decrypt`), or
2. Make a middleware to instantiate the cart after `EncryptCookies`. It's a little bit too early to instantiate cart at the bootstrapping service providers phase.

---

**Edit: Add singleton suggestion**

I think you could do this:

1. Create a new method named `loadCartFromRequest($request)` in your `Cart::class`. This method help you load a cart instance from request during the middleware phase.
2. In your `CartServiceProvider`, you register a singleton of `Cart::class` as usual, but no need to read the request here.
3. Create a middleware, called `CartMiddleware`. This middleware call `app(Cart::class)->loadCartFromRequest($request)`.
4. Then at any other places that you need the cart instance, you can access your cart model from `app(Cart::class)`.

I hope I understand your requirement correctly :)

Comment: So, should I just create a new middleware and copy my code from the `register()` method?

Comment: Or how to create a new singleton in service container with middleware?

Comment: @Alexxosipov added a suggestion

Answer (score 4):

**Why?** Cookie encryption protects data stored in the client's browser.

**The How:**  Laravel uses the EncryptCookies middleware,  this middleware would not yet be processed when your service provider is registered but would be processed for the controller since middlewares are in the routing stack before the request is passed to the controller.

Since I don't know about your cart class and its logic, I can't really recommend what you should do.  Perhaps you need to think about when you are passing the Request object to your class.

Comment: I used Laravel 5.2 and it was fine. My cart class is pretty easy: in construct we check `cart_id` cookie and take a row of cart from my database. This is how: `$this->id = (request()->cookie('cart_id')) ? request()->cookie('cart_id') : false;` if it returns false, we set new cart for this user. I tried to pass $request variable to __construct(), but it still the same :(

Comment: `Cookie encryption protects data stored in the client's browser.` Could you please clarify? As far as I know, encrypting cookies only prevents information disclosure (the user and another person cannot read/understand the contents and semantics of the cookie) and is used to verify the integrity of a cookie. If an attacker intercepts a request with the encrypted cookies, the encryption becomes useless. What do you think?

Comment: If the attacker doesn't have the encryption key, the data is useless since it's the server side that decrypts the content of the cookie.